# How can I find full list all calls to an API

Tags: c#, api, audit, static-code-analysis

I have a very large ASP.Net C# ver 4.8 solution with several projects. The application uses Redis as remote cache. I want to audit the code on regular basis (once a quarter) to get full list of all redis keys. Once I have baseline after initial run, I want to compare and see any recently added keys etc.

Code interacts with Redis through an abstracted layer, `CacheManager`. Some typical calls looks like this.

```
cacheManager.Set("key1", "value1")

myCache.Get("key1")

cache.Set("key2", "value2");
```

Where `cacheManager`, `myCache`, `cache` etc. are local instances of `CacheManager`.

I want to get a full list of `CacheManager` usage along with keys and values. Should I look into Static Code Analysis options or something else?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use Redis, to get all keys and output them to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this from two sides. If you want to find all set methods from your Cache Manager, right click the class name and select Find all references (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> by default). Then go through that list and check all keys.

If the redis instance is only used by this application, you could very wsell open up the `redis-cli` and output all keys to a txt file and analyse it this way. Might also be faster.

```
redis-cli keys * > myKeys.txt
```

If all your keys are prefixed you can of course adapt the query to `keys prefix:*` or whatever. The asterisk is the wildcard.